# Parallel processes not sharing same data

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fork, system-calls

I'm programming a little C code where it exists a variable as a int pointer. What the processes should do is to subtract the value of that variable until it reaches 0. 
The problem is that each process appears to have its own copy of the variable even if the address that the program prints is the same. Does this happens because each process has its own space in memory?

Here's the output:

```
START
Account address: 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 90, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 80, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 70, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 60, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 50, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 40, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 30, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 20, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 10, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Parent substracted 10. Account value: 0, address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 90 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 80 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 70 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 60 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 50 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 40 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 30 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 20 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 10 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
Child substracted 10. Account value: 0 , address 0x7ffee5820be0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

If you want to share memory space, you have a couple of options:

- either look at shared memory - *"POSIX Shared Memory"* or *"System V Shared Memory"*, or
- use threads - either C11/C++11 threads or "pthreads" (i.e. POSIX threads) - which automatically share the same memory space, or
- use **Redis**, which is a very fast, in-memory data structure server (queues, lists, sets, hashes, strings/ints/floats) and then you can share variables (actually atomically) between processes across the world from each other.

Comment: "*either C++ threads*" since C11 there are also native C threads.

Comment: @afk Thank you, I have hopefully edited in your improvement correctly.

Comment: I used pthreads and it works. Thanks alot!

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with your project. Questions and answers are free, so come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post, I think it will explain both why the address seems to be the same for parent and child, and the fact that the entire memory state is not shared between parent and child:

[fork() system call and memory space of the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486873/fork-system-call-and-memory-space-of-the-process)