# Shared object code does not seem to be shared among processes on Linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, shared-objects

The code (aka .text section) of a shared object (.so file) is normally being shared among processes. You can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415075/11016652).

I have written a little example where things seem to behave different.

**In short**: The program proofs that changes made to the code section of a shared object do not affect other instances of the program. Thus the code section of the shared object is not being shared among processes.

**Long explanation**: The code consists of a program (main.c) which loads a .so file (mylib.c).

The library consists of one single function which returns an integer. This integer is stored in the code section among with the machine instructions. If you don't belive the integer is stored in the code section you can run `objdump -d libmy.so`.

The program loads the library and then modifies the integer in the code section of the shared object. Before that the program runs `mprotect()` to avoid a segmentation fault. The value is being changed to the current timestamp.

Now I run the program twice with a delay of 2 seconds so every instance writes its own value to the .so code section. By surprise the value of the first instance is not being overwritten by the value of the second instance.

How is that possible?

I've tested this program on x64 only. Simply save the files and run the bash script.

libmy.c:

```
int getval()
{
    return 123;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int getval();

void unprotect(uint64_t addr)
{
    uint64_t pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    addr -= addr % pagesize;
    if (mprotect((void*)addr, pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC) != 0)
    {
        printf("mprotect failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        int* ip = (int*)((char*)&getval + i);
        if (*ip == 123)
        {
            printf("found value at offset %i\n", i);
            unprotect((uint64_t)ip);
            unprotect((uint64_t)ip + 3);
            *ip = (int)time(NULL);
            printf("value changed successfully\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    while (1)
    {
        printf("getval() returns %i\n", getval());
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

run.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libmy.so libmy.c
gcc main.c -L. -lmy -Wl,-rpath . -o bin
./bin &
sleep 2
./bin
```

Comment: The two sentences in the "In Short" part don't actually follow from one another. See [What are the differences between virtual memory and physical memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14347206/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270 I know the difference between virtual and physical memory. How can there be two values in my example if there is only one physical copy of the code section?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I think the TL;DR you're looking for is that writing to virtual memory can change what physical memory its fulfilled by. There isn't a fixed one-to-one correspondence between virtual memory and physical memory. Many virtual address ranges can be fulfilled by the same physical page, so long you only _read_ from it. As soon are you attempt a write, a new copy of the physical page is made. This is how shared memory when forking a process works. It's also why you `malloc` more memory than you have RAM (so long as you don't write to all of it).

Comment: For related discussions, see [Malloc allocates memory more than RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7504139/11082165), [fork() system call and memory space of the process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27486873/11082165), [What causes page faults?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5684365/11082165), [Does fork() duplicate all the memory of the parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32130868/11082165)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Is the shared library object loaded as shared memory for the program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450801/564341): _"The shared library file is mapped into the programs memory and this is done in a shared way with copy on write for the data, so most of the needed RAM is shared."_

Comment: This is similar to the way `mmap()` works with the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag. The memory is shared until you modify it, then you get a private copy.

Comment: @Barmar So the linker calls `mmap()` with `MAP_PRIVATE`. Could this be the answer? Or is it `libdl`?

Comment: I don't know if it called `mmap()` itself, or uses another system call with similar behavior.

Comment: @Barmar `strace` shows shared objects are mapped with `MAP_PRIVATE` on my Ubuntu system.  And FWIW, `truss` shows the same on Solaris 11.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A shared object is mapped with the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag. This means that the memory is initially shared among all the users, but with the "copy on write" flag set for each page. As a result, if a process modifies the memory they get their own copy, it doesn't affect the other processes that have linked with the same object file.

It's obvious that this is necessary for the data section, since each process is expected to make local changes to this. But it's also done for the text section, even though it's read-only by default. As you discovered, you can override the read-only flag, but since it's still COW you get a private copy when you write to it.

Answer (score 0):

> In short: The program proofs that changes made to the code section of a shared object do not affect other instances of the program. Thus the code section of the shared object is not being shared among processes.

***Of course not!!!!*** if you modify other program's `.text` segment, without it's knowledge, it will surely crash.  Think about having a shared library shared between different users and being modified arbitrarily by one user.  What security vulnerabilities can arise from this!!!!

To make a `.text` segment read-write, you have to specifically allow it.  And of course, bypass all the security implications that that has.  Normally, if you do that, your `.text` segment will be marked as *COPY ON WRITE* and will be copied the first time you happen to change it, making it partially not shared anymore.